# How to enable sound after kernel update on XMBC with cmedia-8783

Tags: 12.10, sound, xbmc

After the last apt-get upgrade the sound-settings on my XMBC-server are gone again.

I fiddled a lot to adjust the Sound-settings so they work with SPDIF-out and DTS but now I am lost again.

There are so many options in alsa-mixer and I guess only one configuration works ;(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the alsa-mixer setting on my machine:

[image: alsa-mixer setting]

alsa-mixer shows 8768, which is strange, but i have the cmedia-8783 soundcard